# Let $F = Z_3$. Is $f(x) = x^4 + x^3 + x + 2$ irreducible in $F[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I'm posting to check if I did this right.

First approach was to check roots:
$f(0) \neq 0$,
$f(1) \neq 0$,
$f(2) \neq 0$.

Second approach: Brute Force

My options for degree 1 were:
 $x$, $x+1$, $x+2$

My options for degree 2 were:
 $x^2$, $x^2 + 1$, $x^2+2$, $x^2+x$, $x^2+x+1$, $x^2+x+2$

I took out $x$, $x^2$, $x^2+x$ because I have a constant at the end, so there is no way these are factors.

After some long divisions, I arrived at the fact that

$\frac{x^4 + x^3 + x + 2}{x^2 +1} = x^2 + x + 2$ with $r = 0$

I concluded that this polynomial is reducible in $F[x]$.

Is this enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do to check that your factorization is correct is multiply it out.

$\begin{align}
(x^2 + 1)(x^2 + x + 2) &= x^2(x^2 + x + 2) + (x^2 + x + 2) \\
&= x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 + x^2 + x + 2 \\&= x^4 + x^3 + 3x^2 + x + 2\\& = x^4 + x^3 + x + 2\end{align} $

Which is indeed what you started with.

Comment: I'm just starting with this topic so just wanted to make sure since I have no professor close to me to check this out. Thank you for responding!

Comment: @chrisoname Happily. Polynomial division works in these settings (they are Euclidean domains), and so as long as you check the coefficients carefully, you can always do what you have done here for any polynomial rings over a field.